# Computing autocorrelation times with R

Tags: r, autocorrelation

Say I have the following data:

```
time, [s]   response
0   42.2322
1   40.5469
2   33.7388
3   23.4911
4   34.9972
5   26.1497
6   38.527
7   21.6063
8   42.7667
9   44.5489
10  44.1784
11  36.4207
12  15.5216
13  46.3163
14  44.6453
15  50.6852
16  18.9666
17  32.9604
18  42.3621
19  5.2577
20  41.2933
21  31.8881
22  28.7433
23  26.3438
24  33.3351
25  66.1519
26  38.5096
27  14.8716
28  39.3075
29  40.7627
30  41.7653
31  58.2
32  51.0653
33  40.4087
34  39.2458
35  21.8875
36  41.4573
37  20.9614
38  44.2727
39  14.4462
40  27.2548
41  49.1083
42  22.2269
43  29.8199
44  27.568
45  15.6135
46  35.5015
47  53.0287
48  36.4141
49  19.3218
50  14.3907
51  19.9225
52  35.6094
53  62.0757
54  47.6391
55  43.3262
56  27.6419
57  35.6522
58  29.949
59  50.0034
60  27.4096
61  20.936
62  12.4265
63  24.6453
64  19.3703
65  31.7393
66  14.3998
67  27.6009
68  22.4643
69  42.5963
70  46.0308
71  52.99
72  42.0841
73  59.0131
74  27.4885
75  37.0328
76  37.2553
77  34.2181
78  39.9436
79  29.6671
80  44.4776
81  45.4403
82  40.345
83  15.3615
84  37.6402
85  42.0906
86  34.0567
87  21.8624
88  50.2167
89  32.9561
90  42.0911
91  44.3579
92  48.4785
93  48.9758
94  18.1752
95  31.2206
96  51.5934
97  23.8705
98  23.6733
99  28.9441
```

I read it with:

```
x=read.table('data')
```

How can I compute the autocorrelation time for the data series?

I can compute the autocorrelation function with

```
acf(x)
```

and I can choose a lag that is below, say, |0.2| for the ACF, but is this not too arbitrary? Is there a predefined function in R to compute the autocorrelation times or do I need to look at the autocorrelation functions for my datasets and choose a sufficiently long lag period for each dataset?

Comment: Could you clarify what an "autocorrelation time" is?

Comment: The period of time after which response values are no longer correlated with each other.

Comment: To do that, you will need to specify (and fit) a model as well as have a quantitative way to determine how small a correlation must be to qualify as  "no longer correlated."